# Add Physics only to the sprites that are within my view

Tags: swift, xcode, physics, tiles, sktilemapnode

I have a tileMap and within it some tileNodes, I am looking to only give physics to the tilesNodes that are within the screen view and as the player navigates the world, the tileNodes that come into screen view get physics and the tileNodes that go out of screen view get their physics removed. Any help would be appreciated, even if it means to completely redo my code.
Thank you.

Here is how i been adding physics to my tiles...

```
static func addPhysicsTo(map: SKTileMapNode){
    let tileSize = map.tileSize
    let halfWidth = CGFloat(map.numberOfColumns) / 2.0 * tileSize.width
    let halfHeight = CGFloat(map.numberOfRows) / 2.0 * tileSize.height
    for col in 0..<map.numberOfColumns
    {
        for row in 0..<map.numberOfRows
        {
            let tileDefinition = map.tileDefinition(atColumn: col, row: row)
            let isUsedTile = tileDefinition?.userData?["Tile"] as? Bool
            if (isUsedTile ?? false)
            {
                let x = CGFloat(col) * tileSize.width - halfWidth
                let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height - halfHeight
                let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tileSize.width, height: tileSize.height)
                let tileNode = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
                tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
                tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: tileSize, center: CGPoint(x: tileSize.width / 2.0, y: tileSize.height / 2.0))
                tileNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
                tileNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
                tileNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                tileNode.physicsBody?.pinned = true
                tileNode.physicsBody?.density = 200.0
                tileNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = GameConstants.physicsConstants.tileCategory
                tileNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = GameConstants.physicsConstants.playerCategory
                //tileNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = GameConstants.physicsConstants.allCategory
                map.addChild(tileNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The player adds an impulse to the Hero with this function in touchesBegun...

```
static func applyImpulse(sprite: SKSpriteNode, touchLocationX: CGFloat, touchLocationY: CGFloat) {
    let impulseX = (sprite.position.x - touchLocationX ) / 10
    let impulseY = (sprite.position.y - touchLocationY ) / 20
    sprite.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(x: impulseX  , y: impulseY))  
}
```

I created a tileNode Class that will activated and deactivate nodes, i just don't know what the rest of the code should look like...

```
class TileNodes: SKSpriteNode {
    var isTileActivated: Bool = false
    {
        didSet {
            physicsBody = isTileActivated ? activatedBody : nil
        }
    }

    private var activatedBody: SKPhysicsBody?
    init(with size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: size)

        //I ASSUME THE CODE GOES HERE

        physicsBody = isTileActivated ? activatedBody : nil
        name = GameConstants.nameConstants.tileName
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Based on some of the things Ive found online, it seems like I need to use didSimulatePhysics() but i don't know how..

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    for node in tileMap[GameConstants.nameConstants.tileName] {
        if let tileNode = node as? TileNodes {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as image. Also we need more information: e.g. how can a player navigate through the world

Comment: Sorry, I've added the code as text, thank you for pointing that out..